# Accessing an ATAPI Zip Drive via a USB-ATA bridge

Tags: usb-storage, zip-drive

I have an old Iomega Zip100 drive (labelled as ATAPI) which I'm trying to access via a USB-ATA/SATA bridge. Under Windows 7, plugging it in brings up an error in Device Manager (USB Mass Storage Device: This device cannot start); under Linux (Ubuntu or Parted Magic), I get messages in `dmesg` as follows:

```
[   79.600104] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[   80.276845] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   80.279191] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[   80.279319] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   80.279489] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   80.279490] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[  104.300076] usb 1-1: reset high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[  106.816100] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  109.400083] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  111.972077] usb 1-1: reset high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[  114.416080] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  116.988076] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  119.525052] usb 1-1: reset high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[  119.605160] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  119.749098] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  122.328071] usb 1-1: reset high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[  122.386670] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  122.531119] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  122.632090] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  122.632124] scsi 5:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  125.204064] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[  129.652662] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  132.708186] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  135.244085] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  137.732086] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  140.280137] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  142.812108] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[  142.897135] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  143.041068] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  145.564480] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[  145.625696] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  145.770217] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/8, error -32
[  145.872236] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
```

I've tried several combinations of jumper settings on the drive (Master, Cable Select / Drive A, Not Drive A); is it possible to access a ZIP drive via such a USB bridge or do I need to plug it into a "proper" IDE channel on a motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

In case of USB/ATAPI you have to hope that ATAPI part negotiates good transfer mode because you have no control over it. Broken pipe means device disconnected, which may signify wrong DMA mode or non-conformant cable
(e)SATA-IDE converter should do different if not better.